# Google Apps Script WebApp Pass html to file

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

This is a followup on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239135/alpha-sort-array-of-html-links-in-anchor-tags-using-javascript/42239494#42239494).

I'm now trying to use a template file so I can pull in some css, etc.  I am publishing this as a web app.  The output should be a list of the files in a Google Drive directory contained in an iframe.

The loading message appears in the iframe and I don't get any syntax errors but the list of files in the directory does not appear.

code.gs:

```
    function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page');
}

function FileList() {
  // my folder ID
  var dir = '[MY_FOLDER_ID]';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dir);
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var filelist = [];
  var file, name, url, idName = []; 
  while (contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    idName = name.toUpperCase();
    url = file.getUrl();
    // add table row html to filelist array
    filelist = filelist.concat('<tr><td><a id="' + idName + '" target="_blank" href="' + url + '">' + name + '</a></td></tr>');
  }
  // alpha sort filelist array  
  filelist.sort();
  // turn filelist into a string
  filelist = filelist.join(""); 

  return filelist;
}
```

page.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
     function onSuccess(foo) {
      var table = document.getElementById('output');
      table.innerHTML = foo;    
     }   
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getFileList();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="output">Loading Files...</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is syntax/typo in your code here:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getFileList();
```

it should be

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).FileList();
```

Since the function name in google script is FileList and not getFileList().

**Tip:** You can use inspect or developer console in google chrome to see your errors when you run web app.(Not sure if you knew it.)

Hope that helps, good luck!